# grunt jshint asks to set esversion to 6 even though it is set to greater

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint

In .jshintrc, the `esversion` is set to 9(to support latest features) https://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion

With this, if we run jshint via grunt, we are getting the below error,

```
'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6').
```

If we change esversion to 6 back, we are not getting this error, but not able to use async/await. Ideally, esversion 9 should include the features of esversion 6. Is there anything missing here? Any changes to grunt also required? Thanks in advance.

If we run jshint manually, there is no error. This error comes only in grunt.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. `grunt-contrib-jshint` has its own `jshint` dependency and as of now it is set to `~2.9.6`.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/286

They have to update their dependency too